# Jump OnCollision() Script not working

Tags: c#, debugging, vector, unity-game-engine

**basically, I'm trying to make a game that is based off automatically hopping as soon as the ground is hit**(**the Controller I'm using is the pre-made one that can be imported**).In order to do this, I removed the jump function from the controller script and added a script called "Cube" which reads as the following:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Cube : MonoBehaviour {

        void OnCollisionStay (Collision col)
        {
        if (col.gameObject.name == "Blue") {
            Rigidbody rig;
             rig= GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
            rig.velocity = new Vector3 (0, 8, 0);

            print ("collison detected");
        }
            }
        }
```

after doing this, I expected a controllable character which jumps as soon as you hit the ground because of the "OnCollisionStay()" trigger. **However, instead I get a rapid jump that happens even when I'm in the air which looks like this**:

**https://youtu.be/ILtRac_RgLg**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, **undo** everything modification you performed to the `RigidbodyFirstPersonController` script. If possible, delete it and re-import a clean one from Unity.

Select your `RigidBodyFPSController` GameObject, Look at the `RigidbodyFirstPersonController` script attached to it in the Editor. Under it there is a setting called **Advanced Settings**. Under **Advanced Settings**, there is variable called **Shell Offset**. Change **Shell Offset** from its default value of `0` to `0.5`. Play again and this problem should be gone. If that didn't work, bump it up more. This should solve your problem.

[image]

Comment: I tried bumping it up all the way up to 10, still having problems Update: im able to jump and look around but i cant move Update 2: had to check air controll

Comment: @SpikyCat It is supposed to be jumping now.. Is it jumping ? If it is, what's the problem you are having?

Comment: Everything was fixed, i had to just turn aircontrol on

Answer (score 0):

You are not in the air as the gravity is effecting on it. Whenever you are exiting the collision your y-axis upward velocity is not working and gravity force is taking place downward.

Disable `gravity` in FPSController's `Rigidbody` component if you don't want to use gravity.

Comment: Now the FPSController cant move at all